# Negative-Gm Oscillator Biasing Conditions

Tags: mosfet, oscillation, negative-resistance

I have some questions regarding the circuit below. I need to ensure two conditions are met. The output is taken from the drains of the cross-coupled pair. I think the drain voltages (1.198V) are not present at the same time during operation, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm pretty sure they switch back and forth.

1) I need to keep M2 in the saturation region. From my understanding, the cross-coupled pair will act as switches and turn off and on. Allowing for that 1.198V to always be present at the drain of M2. Therefore, $$1.198 \geq V_{bias,t} - V_{th} $$
$$V_{bias,t} \leq 1.198 + 500mV \leq 1.698 $$

Is this correct?

2) Bias M1 in the subthreshold region. Would I simply set the M1 bias voltage to a value of 1.675V? Because:

$$1.675 - 1.198 = 452mV$$

[image]

Comment: Is M1 symmetrical on source and drain?

Comment: What transistors are these? Are they idealized symetrical devices, as @analogsystemsrf was asking about? The symbol they use is that of a dedicated transistor on seperate substrate (as highlighted by the circuit around them). Then again, the schematic software world is known to take significant liberty in the symbols (such as the fact that the symbol here is that of a depletion-mode device, but I'm quite sure you are using an enhancement mode device going by the voltages you are biasing them with)

Comment: I changed the tail current transistor to the same devices but forgot to update the image. They're RF nfet transistors. And yes, M1 is symmetrial on the source and drain. But I forgot to mention that M1 will also have a 250mVpp AC signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) *M2 needs to be in saturation*

The voltage of interest is the common source voltage, not the outputs at \$1.198V\$. Although the cross-coupled pair transistors will act like a kind of switches, they need a certain \$v_{GS}\$ to keep working. This gives us \$v_{DS2} = 1.198V - v_{GS}\$. In order to be in saturation, we require that

\$v_{DS2} > v_{bias,t} - v_{TH} \Rightarrow v_{bias,t} < 1.198V - v_{GS} + v_{TH}\$

So your design for M2 is along the lines of:

- \$L_2\$ is big enough to increase its output impedance, and to improve matching for the current mirror
- \$\frac{W_2}{L_2}\$ is big enough to drive your bias current (which I assume is a design specification) with a small enough \$v_{GS2}\$.

2) *M1 needs to be in the subthreshold region*

I don't see anything particularly wrong with your reasoning. However, you might want to consider that:

- when the outputs diverge, the voltage that goes down will take the role of the source. \$v_{GS1}\$ increases, and M1 may go out of weak inversion... It kind of depends on the requirements whether or not this is ok.
- when you connect the bulk to ground and the source is at a higher voltage, then this results in a higher \$v_{TH}\$ due to the body effect. So you have a little bit more headroom to keep M1 in the subthreshold region.